# Regular expression to add a space before the last in a sequence of consecutive capital letters

Tags: c#, regex

Have given up on this after spending too much time trying to figure it out, and thought I'd see if someone else wants a go!

I need a regular expression that will insert a space before the last consecutive capital letter where there are more than two consecutive capital letters.

E.g's:

```
A = A
AB = AB
ABC = AB C
ABCD = ABC D
abCdefGHijkLMNop = abCdefGHijkLM Nop
```

Comment: Why a regex and not a 'for'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replacement

```
string output=Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=[A-Z]{2})(?=[A-Z][^A-Z]|[A-Z]$)", " ");
```

"replaces" the zero-length point between the last two capital letters in a chain with a space, i.e. inserts a space.

Comment: Don't you need a `$` at the end of the first option in the alternation? Also, your replacement show empty string, not a space.

Comment: The alternation is "captial followed by a non-captial, or capital at the end of the string"... I think it's appropriate. (But good catch on me not actually inserting _anything_ \o/)

Answer (score 4):

This regexp will group:

```
([A-Z]{2,})([A-Z]+)
```

then you just have to output group 1, a space, group 2

Comment: fixed :), anyway your answer is better ^^

Comment: Does this match to two groups with the first being the entire string?  [When I test this](http://rubular.com/r/N3bMOZXVrO), group 1 is the first part of the match `LM` in the last example, group 2 is `N`.  Is there a way to have that entire first part of the string match as group 1 (or is my test wrong)?

Comment: @Walls I think by `output` you need to read `replace with` rather than `use as your entire result`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "ABC";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"([A-Z]{2,})([A-Z])", "$1 $2"); 

Console.WriteLine(str);    // "AB C"
```